# Implementing Asprise OCR into your own code

Tags: java, ocr, implementation

I have downloaded the Asprise OCR SDK to my system, but I am unable to implement OCR in my own code. I am receiving no errors until runtime.

The error I am now getting is : Error: Could not find or load main class

Has anybody attempted to implement OCR in their own code, if so how?

I followed the developers guide from Asprise but have been unsuccessful

Testing code:
import com.asprise.ocr.Ocr;
import java.io.*;

public class OCRTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ocr.setUp(); // one time setup
    Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
    ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST);
    String s = ocr.recognize(new File[] { new File("images\test.png") }, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL,
            Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT, 0, null);
    System.out.println("RESULT: " + s);
    ocr.stopEngine();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
I have extracted OCR from images using tesseract library

[please go through this link][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract


public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      File inputFile=new File(filePath);
            System.out.println("processing file ...."+inputFile.getName());
            Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); //
            instance.setLanguage("hin+eng");
            BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(inputFile);
            String ocrText = instance.doOCR(ImageHelper.convertImageToGrayscale(bufferedImage));
            System.out.println(ocrText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... but that's like I want to know how to make apple juice but you are telling me about cooking soup. :~